# setOnFocusChangeListener doesnt hide Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, hide

Im trying to hide my keyboard on lost focus on the setOnFocuslistener. for some reason it doesnt work...this is my xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/AgePicker"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black_overlay" />
```

and my code:

```
setAge.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                String sAge = setAge.getText().toString();
                Age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(setAge.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (Age < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(DietActivity.this,
                            "Enter Computable Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

            }

        }
    });
```

and i also use these in my xml:

```
 android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

please help me. all i want is for the keyboard to hide when edittext has lost focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was kinda trivial but I'll post my answer maybe it'll help some other pool soul... 
here is my code:

setAge.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String sAge = setAge.getText().toString();

            if (isNumeric(sAge) ) {
                Age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(setAge.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (Age < 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(DietActivity.this,
                            "Enter Computable Values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what currently has focus...if its another editText that takes focus then this might be bringing up the keypad...try to explicitly give focus to a different element.

Comment: lets say when i press the bg of my main activity i want to hide keyboard or different buttons which are not other edittexts... why doesnt it work for me?